# Time complexity and space complexity of code to generate all binary strings without consecutive 1’s

Tags: java, string, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

I solved the question generate all binary strings without consecutive 1’s but I found another solution to this question is another website with a different approach but I am not able to understand which algorithm has less time complexity and space complexity. Here are both codes:

**My approach**

```
public class Main {

    static boolean check(int k, int mid, char binary[]) {

        if (binary.length % 2 == 0) {

            int sum = 0;
            int sum1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= mid - 1; i++) {
                sum = sum + binary[i];
            }
            for (int j = binary.length - 1; j > mid - 1; j--) {
                sum1 = sum1 + binary[j];
            }
            if (sum == sum1) {
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        } else {
            int sum2 = 0;
            int sum3 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= mid - 1; i++) {
                sum2 = sum2 + binary[i];
            }
            for (int j = binary.length - 1; j > mid; j--) {
                sum3 = sum3 + binary[j];
            }
            if (sum2 == sum3) {
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }
    }

    static void all(int index, int k, int mid, char binary[]) {
        if (index == k) {
            if (check(k, mid, binary)) {
                System.out.println(binary);

            }
            return;
        }
        binary[index] = '0';
        all(index + 1, k, mid, binary);
        binary[index] = '1';
        all(index + 1, k, mid, binary);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 5;
        int mid = k / 2;
        char binary[] = new char[k];
        all(0, k, mid, binary);
    }
}
```

**Website approach**

```
class Main {

    static void equal(int n, String left, String right, int di) {

        if (n == 0) {

            if (di == 0)
                System.out.print(left + right + " ");
            return;
        }

        if (n == 1) {
            if (di == 0) {
                System.out.print(left + "0" + right + " ");
                System.out.print(left + "1" + right + " ");
            }
            return;
        }

        if ((2 * Math.abs(di) <= n)) {

            equal(n - 2, left + "0", right + "0", di);

            equal(n - 2, left + "0", right + "1", di - 1);

            equal(n - 2, left + "1", right + "0", di + 1);

            equal(n - 2, left + "1", right + "1", di);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 5;
        equal(n, "", "", 0);
    }
}
```